# Prolog - list of range of values, not including range

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to create a list of a range of values like rngList(20, 25, X) . = [21,22,23,24]
but its including the last value and giving me [21,22,23,24,25]. Any ideas where I'm going wrong here?

```
rngList(X, X, []) .
rngList(X, Y, [Z|Tail]) :- Z is X+1, rngList(Z, Y, Tail) .
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are including Z = X+1 in the result. You need to write this (note I also check X < Y to avoid "excursion" into an infinite loop in case this is called with X > Y.

Additionally we can add a cut on the first clause because if it succeeds there is no need to attempt the second one:

```
rngList(X, X, [])  :- !
rngList(X, Y, [X|Tail]) :- X < Y, XX is X+1, rngList(XX, Y, Tail) .
```

Also, a more "logical" predicate would want to fail for "the empty solution" (as in "are there any solutions" "NO!"):

```
rngList(X, Y, [X]) :- X+1 =:= Y,!.
rngList(X, Y, [X|More]) :- X+1 < Y, XX is X+1, rngList(XX, Y, More).
```

And so:

```
?- rngList(3,5,L).
L = [3, 4].

?- rngList(3,4,L).
L = [3].

?- rngList(3,3,L).
false.

?- rngList(3,2,L).
false.
```

**Update**

To also exclude the first value to need to call the above predicate as a secondary predicate:

```
rngList(X, Y, L) :- 
   X < Y+1, 
   XX is X+1, 
   rngList2(XX, Y, L).

rngList2(X, Y, [X]) :- 
   X+1 =:= Y,!.

rngList2(X, Y, [X|More]) :- 
   X+1 < Y, 
   XX is X+1, 
   rngList2(XX, Y, More).
```

And so:

```
?- rngList(3,6,L).
L = [4, 5].

?- rngList(3,5,L).
L = [4].

?- rngList(3,4,L).
false.

?- rngList(3,3,L).
false.

?- rngList(3,2,L).
false.
```

It would be interesting to extend `rngList/3` so that it also computes one or both of the boundaries from the result list, i.e. becomes a more complete predicate, as in:

```
?- rngList(3,Y,[4,5]).
Y = 6.
```

Comment: This does remove the last value, but now it includes the first value which I am also attempting to avoid

Comment: @BunkyGiordano Updated for that case